# Proving a scalar function is differentiable (the function is given in terms of an integral)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a continuous and derivable function such that $f(x)>0$ for all $t$ and let $G(x,y)=\int_{y^2}^{x^3} f(t)dt$. Show that $G(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and decide whether it has an extremum at that point.

The attempt at a solution (I've edited it after Tzakrevskiy's corrections):

I know that $G(0,0)=0$ and, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x,y)=3x^2f(x^3)$ and $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x,y)=-2yf(y^2)$. So $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x}(0,0)=0=\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}(0,0)$

I want to show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|G(x,y)-(G(0,0)+<\nabla G(0,0),(x,y)>)|}{\|(x,y)\|}=0$.

This limit is equal to $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|\int_{y^2}^{x^3} f(t)dt|}{\|(x,y)\|}$. I don't know how to show that this limit exists and is $0$.

For the other part, (decide whether the function $G$ has an extremum at the origin), I know that a necessary condition is that $\nabla G(0,0)=(0,0)$, and this condition is satisfied. Could it be that $G(0,0)$ is a saddle point?

$G(0,0)=0$. Consider the two points $(\epsilon,0)$ and $(-\epsilon,0)$ for some $\epsilon>0$, then $G(\epsilon,0)=\int_0^{\epsilon} f(t)dt>0$, because $f(t)>0$ for every $t$, and $G(-\epsilon,0)=\int_0^{-\epsilon} f(t)dt=-\int_{-\epsilon}^0 f(t)dt<0$

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if what I've done so far is correct and guide me on the part where I got stuck.

Comment: In fact, $\partial_x G(x,y) = 3x^2 f(x^3)$, therefore $\partial_x G(0,y)=0$. Same goes for $\partial_y G(x,0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've applied the fundamental theorem of calculus wrong. Still I have problems to calculate the limit, now I edit my post with your correction.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of questions become less intimidating once we introduce an antiderivative of $f$, called $F$. Then $G(x,y)=F(x^3)-F(y^2)$. Note that $F$ is strictly increasing, because $f$ is positive. It should be clear  now that $G$ does not have an extremum at $(0,0)$, just by looking at what happens on the axis $y=0$.

To show differentiability, it suffices to show that each term $F(x^3)$ and $F(y^2)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. Note that $F$ is differentiable as a function of one variable (since $f$ is continuous) and thus $(F(x^3))'=3x^2 F'(x^3)=0$ when $x=0$
Write this down as 
$$\lim_{ x\to 0} \frac{ F(x^3) }{x}=0\tag{1}$$

Once you write down that scary-looking definition of differentiability for $F(x^3)$, it simplifies into
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|F(x^3)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$
which is a direct consequence of (1).

Comment: Sorry if the answer is too obvious: I don't get how do you conclude that the last limit is $0$ from $(1)$, could you explain that?